# how to call a method when a button is clicked in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

```
<%!  
 public void display()  
 {  
     System.out.println("Hai");  
 }
 %>

<input type="submit" value="touch me" method="display()"/>
```

> > I have a jsp page like above. How can i call a method when the 
> >     user clicking the button.The above code is not working. How i do it without javascript...

Answer (score -2):

You are confusing server side and client side. The code is generated on the server side, your user clicks on the client side. If you want to call server side code from the client side you need to look into [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).
If you want to carry out events on the client side you need to use javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript>
 function alert() {
  alert("Hai");
 }
</script
<input type="submit" value="touch me" onClick="alert();"/>
```

Comment: thanks morris... Eventhough is anyother way to do the same thing in JSP?

Comment: as I said your JSP runs on the _server side_, it is compiled and sent via the internet to the _client side_. So the user clicks on the button _in their browser_. If you want that click to do something synchronously then you can submit a form, if you want it to do something asynchronously then you need to use ajax.