# button element call java method on click

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, onclick

I want to create a button in my jsp page, that on click it will call the `CancelJob(jobId)` method in Java in file `A.java`.
I'm creating the button in a java method called `foo()` in the same file `A.java` ,

```
String foo(){

String jobId;  
...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<input type='button' value='Cancel'>");
...
}

CancelJob(jobId){
...
}
```

how should the element of the button be build ? Please add an explanation because I'm new to this topic

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909262/how-to-call-a-method-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-jsp/14909403#14909403)

Comment: I need to call a java method not javascript function!

Comment: ok, let's say I want to use a form submit can you show me a way to do it

Comment: if I found something in google that i understand, i won't ask here

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such things just with JSP. Either [JSF](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) or [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/overview) is required. Well, you can also do purely on the client side with applets and JavaScript but at these times maybe better not.